# mysql-connector-java driver not found when upgrading past 5.1.39

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, datanucleus

My Spring Boot App that uses DataNucleus as a Persistence Manager works just fine with this mySQL version in my maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
```

with connections defined with the new name per the upgrade process in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html):

```
 properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest mySQL connector 6.0.6 - but even if I upgrade to any version above the one i'm using (5.1.42 for example)

this is the new maven entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

when i switch to this and the new driver name

I get a pretty clear error

```
The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
```

The rest of my connection info is defined as

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass", "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
            properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", url);
            properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName", login);
            properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword", password);
            properties.setProperty("org.jpox.identifier.case", "PreserveCase");
            properties.setProperty("datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll", "true");
            properties.setProperty("datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll", "true");
            properties.setProperty("datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables", "true");
```

Any advice?

Comment: Might I suggest that you read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html)?

Comment: never! :) yeah I'm just missing something - i get the same error with the driver name in the docs: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

Answer (score 1):

update mysql dependency with `6.* version`  :-

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks - i updated my question to add some clarity - i get this error when i update to the new version 6.x.  I wonder if the driver isn't in the maven distro - i see in the docs i may need to install the jar manually. ?

Answer (score 0):

this turned out to be something funky on my machine - deleting my .m2 repo and forcing an update with `mvn clean install -U` cleared it up.